# Compile only some classes in project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to only build certain classes? I am testing code in one part of the application and I don't want to have to change it all across the program if it is not going to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

- Select the file you want to compile, then select the "Compile" item in the "Build" menu
- **Create a new target** in your project (target dedicated for this debugging) using item "New Target" of the "Project" menu (Xcode3), then only include the classes/files you want to build in this Xcode target.

If you choose to create a dedicated target, you can easily switch between this new target (to compile only the selected classes) and the main target (to compile the whole app) and vice-versa, at any time.

*(if you only need to compile one class for the day until you finish your refactoring but won't need this later, it's probably not worth creating a target; But creating a target could be useful if you intend to test this class on its own in multiple occasions during your development phases)*

Comment: Should I create a new application? Empty application, view based, etc?

Comment: No need to do that you can keep your same project, same app, and only add a target to the existing project. That's what targets are for (one of their usage at least).

Comment: When I create a new target it gives me three categories (Application, Framework & Library, and Other). Under Application, it gives me the basic things like empty application, single view, tabbed, etc. Under Framework & Library I have the option of Cocoa Touch Static Library, and under Other I have the option of Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle.

Comment: Are u using Xcode3 or Xcode4? If I choose "New **target**" under the "Cocoa Touch" I only have "Application"/"Static Library"/"Unit Test Bundle". I select Application, give it a name add it to the project, then I have a new target (and can then in Xcode and the navigator select the files I include in this target, create new files only needed to make a sample app to test only some files, etc… it depends on your needs.

Comment: I'm using Xcode4. I'll see how I can implement what you just said. Thank you.

Comment: You may find [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html) interesting then.